# Three level multilevel model in r

Tags: regression, panel-data, multilevel-analysis, cross-section, growth-mixture-model

I am conducting an analysis looking at trust across a range of 30 countries between 2002-2018. I am using repeated cross sectional survey data.
My data is structured so that individuals(level 1) are nested within country-waves(level 2) which are nested within countries (level 3).
I have done two level models before but I am confused with three level models. I do not know how to fit the null model in r. I want to see how much of variance in trust is between countries, between country-wave and between individuals. So far I have used this code to build the null model but the variances I get don't make sense.

```
Nullmodel<-lmer(trust~(1|country/country_waves),data = data)
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that they don't make sense?

Comment: They are very small, less than 1

Comment: That's not necessarily a problem.